# Issue loading images and GithubPages

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

I seem to be having some issues with a recent project I uploaded and have hosted on GitHub pages. 
One image on the site dose not seem to be loading, I have checked the relevant paths and everything seems fine. 
The other images on the page load up so i'm not too sure what's going on.

Here is the repo for the page: 
https://github.com/Karan-Ghatt/HomeRemoval

The page: 
https://karan-ghatt.github.io/HomeRemoval/   ----- issue is on the 'services' section of the page, the first image in the carousel dose not load.

The index.html file contains the relevant code.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: https://karan-ghatt.github.io/assets/images/testbackground1.jpg does not exist.

Comment: @Roy That's rather strange, I can find the file in my assets folder, along it all the other images that seem to be loading. Here is the link to testbackground1.jpg: 
https://github.com/Karan-Ghatt/HomeRemoval/blob/master/assets/images/testbackground1.jpg

All the other images seem to be able load from the assets folder without any issue, not too sure why.